# C# inheritance -> hierarchy of classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hej guys,

I have a problem understanding the process of inheriting in C#. I am working on a homework and I would like to share my code I came up with. I include the task as well.

The task:

```
    Work 1:
    Develop a hierarchic structure of classes: shape, circle and cylinder:

    Write the base class Shape which has two fields x and y coordinates The function
    Display() returns a text string, which contains the point position.

    The derived classes Circle and Cylinder inherit x , y coordinates and the method
    Display() from base class Shape. You define the new necessary fields and methods
    and you override the method Display() to return a text string with the coordinates,
    the area and/or the volume.

    The computing formulas are:
     Circle area : p * r 2
     Cylinder area: (2*p * r 2 ) + (2*p * r * h)
     Cylinder volume: p * r 2 * h
```

And this is the code I have:

Class Shape:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
    class Shape
    {
    public int xCoordinate = 0;
    public int yCoordinate = 2;

    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The position of the point is: [{0};{1}].", xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }
}
}
```

Class Circle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
class Circle : Shape
{
    public override void Display()
    {
        double PI = Math.PI;
        double radius = 2;
        double circleArea = (PI * radius * radius);
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is: {0:F2}", circleArea);
    }

}
}
```

Class Cylinder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
class Cylinder : Shape
{
    public override void Display()

    {
        double PI = Math.PI;
        double radius = 2;
        double height = 5.5;
        double cylinderArea = (2* PI * radius * radius) + (2 * PI * radius * height);
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the cylinder is: {0:F2}", cylinderArea);
        double cylinderVolume = (PI * radius * radius * height);
        Console.WriteLine("The volume of the cylinder is: {0:F3}\n", cylinderVolume);
    }
}
}
```

And main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A: Work 1\n");
        Shape position = new Shape();
        position.Display();

        Circle circleArea = new Circle();
        circleArea.Display();

        Cylinder cylinderArea = new Cylinder();
        cylinderArea.Display();

    }
}
}
```

I would like to know where I am getting it wrong. The idea of inheritance is a little difficult for me to understand. How can I improve this exercise to fulfill the task?

Thank you for your answers! V.

EDIT:

I have edited the code so now there should be proper inherting. One last question. Where should I put the code Console.WriteLine to get the output?

Class Shape:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
class Shape
{
    public int xCoordinate = 0;
    public int yCoordinate = 2;

    public string Display()
    {
        string xCoordinateString = xCoordinate.ToString();
        string yCoordinateString = yCoordinate.ToString();
        return xCoordinateString + yCoordinateString;
    }
}
}
```

Class Circle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
class Circle : Shape
{
    public new string Display()
    {
        double PI = Math.PI;
        double radius = 2;
        double circleArea = (PI * radius * radius);
        string circleAreaString = circleArea.ToString();
        return circleAreaString;
    }

}
}
```

Class cylinder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_Work_1
{
class Cylinder : Circle
{
    public string Display(double radius, double PI)
     {

        double height = 5.5;
        double cylinderArea = (2* PI * radius * radius) + (2 * PI * radius * height);
        string cylinderAreaString = cylinderArea.ToString();
        double cylinderVolume = (PI * radius * radius * height);
        string cylinderVolumeString = cylinderVolume.ToString();
        return cylinderVolumeString + cylinderAreaString;
    }
}
}
```

Main class remained unchanged.
Thanks, V.

LAST EDIT:

I have change the Main class code so now there is Console.WriteLine code like this:

```
Shape position = new Shape();
Console.WriteLine(position.Display());
```

Last problem I have, is that when I run the application I get the same number for Circle Area and Cylinder Area. It looks like the Display method in class Cylinder is using the return value from class Circle. How is this possible?

Comment: You say you want to know where you're getting it wrong. What do you think is wrong? Are you not getting the answers you expect?

Comment: Instead of duplicating the code for calculating the area of a circle you should think of composition when creating the cylinder class. A cylinder can be represented as a circle and a hight. Then use properties of the circle to calculate volume and area of the cylinder

Comment: @Rune, i thought that too, however the instructions tell him that the `Cylinder` class inherits only the coordinates from `Shape`. Possibly it's worded badly.

Comment: yes, i think it should inherit from the Class Circle, because otherwise I would have to declare the radius and PI again, right? But the problem is I am not sure how to do that :/

Comment: @Vojtech: you write `class Cylinder : Circle` to make the inheritance

Comment: Yes, I got it. But I am not sure how can I inherit the values of PI and radius from the circle class. I tried to use the keyword base, but that is only for the base class shape.

Comment: I have edited the question with new code!

Comment: @Vojtech it should definately _not_ inherit from circle. That fails the is-a "test" I wrote composition deliberately.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett It doesn't say anything about circle not being allowed to expose a method that returns the area of the circle which is the only thing needed for Cylinder. I'd go as far as say that to me it looks like the instructor set up a trap. Looking for those that didn't understand when to use inheritance to derive cylinder from circle and for those that understood when to use composition not to duplicate an already implemented concept

Comment: ok, so if I make the cylinder class derived from class Shape and not Circle, how can I then inherit the the variable radius so I dont have to declare it again?

Comment: @RuneFS and btw: I am supposed to use get/set properties. For example in Circle class I did it like this:                     public double radius = 2;
        public double Radius
        {
            get
            {
                return radius;
            }
            set
            {
                radius = value;
            }
        } Is it correct?

Comment: you don't inherit it, that's the point. Composition means you're going to have a member in Cylinder that's a circle. That member should have a property called area and one called Radius which is all you need to know. You'll only need radius for the calculation of the area of the cylinder. The rest can be based on the area of the circle and the hight of the cylinder

Comment: @RuneFS I am sorry, now I am lost with this. Dont know what you mean by member in Cylinder. The member will be a circle and it will have the property radius which is taken from the Circle class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to move the radius and height to class level, like this:

```
class Circle : Shape
{
   public double radius = 2;
   ...

class Cylinder : Circle
{
   public double height = 5.5;
   ...
```

And your `Display()` is not good now, it was better before the edit. It should be parameterless and it should `override` your base method.
`Display()` in `Shape`:

```
public virtual string Display()
{
   return "[" + this.xCoordinate + ", " + this.yCoordinate + "]";
}
```

`Display()` in `Circle`:

```
public override string Display()
{
   return base.Display() + Environment.NewLine + 
       "Area = " + (Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius).ToString();
}
```

`Display()` in `Cylinder`:

```
public override string Display()
{
   return base.Display() + Environment.NewLine + 
       "Volume = " + (Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius * this.height).ToString();
}
```

To write the results use:

```
Circle myCircle = new Circle();
Console.WriteLine(myCircle.Display());

Cylinder myCylinder = new Cylinder();
Console.WriteLine(myCylinder.Display());
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really nice solution! But my output now is this: Output from Shape, Output from Circle, Output from Shape again, outpus from circle again, output from Cylinder. How can I have only one from each?

Comment: @Vojtech: for the desired output, just remove the `base.Display() + Environment.NewLine` call from the methods.

Comment: Nevermind, now I get it, it was because of calling of the Circle method Display .. when I call only the Cylinder, it works perfect!

Comment: a cylinder is not a circle, modelling a cylinder as a circle is misuse of inheritance

Comment: @RuneFS: that's true in some graphic application, but in this scenario it's perfectly ok to make that inheritance

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be easier for you to understand inheriting  from a real life example.

Lets say you have a Person, A Person has an ID and a name. Now, lets say there is a cop, a cop is inheriting from a person, why ? because every cop is firstly a Person (He has a name and an ID), and only then you can tell he is a cop if he has **other EXTRA** details, like cop id and weapon.

It is the same at OOP, a inheriting class (the child class) has the same properties as the inherited class (the father class), but has extra stuff on it, just like your homework, a Circle Class has more unique stuff, added to the Shape Class. Instead of writing all of the shape stuff all over again in the circle, we are inheriting from the Shape Class and adding extra info inside the Circle Class.

That makes things easier for us and for other programmers understand what the software objects are, and how they are connected between themself and are used to resemble objects in the "real world" (If you have for example an Information System for managing work force, you can have a father class of a "Worker" and a child class of Supervisor", because every supervisor is firstly a worker).

Hope it helps.

*And for your specific homework:*

What I would do in your specific homework is changing the inheritance so that a **Circle is inheriting from a shape and a Cylinder is inheriting from a Circle**. Because every Cylinder is also a circle, with extra properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for the real life example. Now it is more clear to me! I changed the class Cylinder so it inherits properties from the Circle and now it works like a charm!!!

Comment: a cylinder is not a circle. a circle is a 2 dimensional object a cylinder is a 3 dimensional object with a circular base. That's not a candidate for inheritance but composition

Comment: @RuneFS Well, we are not mathematicians and my explanation is focusing about inheritance with more and better examples. Not to say we are not always have to resemble the real word (We are programmers, not physicians or mathematicians). As you can see, more people agree with the `cylinder->circle` inheritance, and the question author says the answer helped him to understand inheritance better. But if voting down my answer made you happy, you're welcome.

Comment: I voted it down because your answer portrays one of the most common misuses of inheritance and thus helped him _misunderstand_ the concept. Take a look at the articles I've linked to for mor information.

Comment: I agree with Alon_A, we are programers and we make ABSTRACTIONS of real world problems. If we can make better and/or easier applications by twisting the real world it's ok to do that. In some graphic application it's not ok to make the `cylinder->circle` inheritance, but for this example is perfectly ok. Mathematicians also abstract reality, they see everything as ideal. Physicians deal with the real world, so they can only ignore some minor variables in calculations.

Comment: @Mentoliptus it's not an abstraction (abstraction is throwing away information to focus on a part of the available information) it's a misrepresentation which is always a bad idea. The idea for OO was from the begining to represent the objects of the real world (as the user sees them) in that context misrepresenting the real world is not OO

Answer (score 1):

Shapes are a classic textbook example of inheritance. Unfortunately it's also a case that's very difficult to get right.

The base rule in inheritance is that you can model a is-a relationship with inheritance.

You can say that a rectangle is a shape, you can also say that a square is a shape. Mathematically you can also say that every square is a rectangle. However if you derive square from rectangle you are going to have to have a chat with [Lisskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). [A square is modellingwise not a rectangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Take this example (further explanation of the problems that might arise are given by the linked to articles)

```
public class Rectangle : Shape{
   public virtual int Width{get;set}
   public virtual int Height{get;set}
}

public class Square : Rectangle{
   public override int Width{get{return Height;} set{Height = value;}}
}
```

the some where in your code you have

```
rect.Height = 10;
rect.Width = 5;
```

The second line might change the Height because of problems with substituting a square for a rectangle.

The same is true for circle and cylinder. How many circles with a radius of 0.2" can you draw on a pieces of paper with the area of 4 sqr inches? how many cylinders? I haven't calculated the former but the answer to the latter is none. It's a 3 dimensional shape and can't be drawn in 2 dimensional space. How ever you can construct a cylinder based on a circle and the knowledge of the cylinders height. Such a relationship is modelled with composition.

In this particular case you could do

```
abstract class Shape{
   public abstract double Area{get;} 
}

class Cylinder : Shape{
private Circle baseCircle;
private double height;

public override double Area{
get{//use height and baseCircle for the calculation left. 
    //Actual code left out because it's homework}
}
```

and the same goes for the volume use height and the area of the baseCircle to calculate the volumen.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! What do you mean by line 'override Area' -> is it supposed to be a variable? Or another class?

Comment: @Vojtech it overrides the abstract property with the same name of Shape (I was a bit sloppy in the original which is now corrected)

Comment: The public properties with getters and setters, and the read-only `Area` property are a better solution, but it's a step further from what Vojtech asked. We provided a more simple solution for his assignment.

Comment: @Mentoliptus " You define the new necessary fields and methods" How's that a step fulutirther away from what was asked?. No you did not provide a simpler soon you provided a solution with obvious misuse of inheritance (for more on the subject http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MisUsingInheritance). The only relation between a cylinder and a circle is that you need the circle concept to create a cylinder. That by no means make a cylinder a circle and modelling it as such is plain wrong. Common but none the less wrong. That kind of inheritance leads to artificial dependencies. The devil or maintenance

Comment: @RuneFS From the code he posted and the questions he asked, he didn't ask for fields or read-only properties. Everyone could solve the problem for him. I simply answered his questions, not solved his assignment for him. If we talk about real-world problems and inheritance, this example would use abstract classes or interfaces for common properties of the `Circle` and `Cylinder`, and separate the logic in different classes with a common abstract parent or the same interface. The URL you posted doesn't make sense for this problem. The comment is too short to explain everything :(

Comment: @Mentoliptus since the article talks about why ImplementationInheritance is a bad idea and suggest that you use composition instead and seeing that you use ImplementationInheritance and I suggest to use composition instead I say it makes quite a lot of sense.

Comment: @RuneFS The first thing that makes no sense is why make the `Bird->Pig` inheritance. The example with `Animal` is ok, but you still could add a `Mammal` class if you'd need a `Dog` class. Composition makes sense if you implement the `Area` and `Volume` as  methods or properties, if you put the calculation in the `Display` or `ToString` methods it's perfectly ok to use inheritance. This is an Object Oriented Design issue, not an implementation issue. The point of this discussion: your -1 is not ok for the reasons you provide.

Comment: @Mentoliptus my -1 was because of your answer being misleading, you've only supported that by repeating a misunderstanding of basic OO concepts. Read the article again and sustitute cylinder for bird and circle for pig and volume for fly. The argument in the article is the same and still holds.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4355/discussion-between-mentoliptus-and-rune-fs)

Answer (score 0):

The homework question asks you to return a text string from display and currently you are returning void.  You need to change the method signature to return string and then adjust your calling code to display that string using (Console.WriteLine).

Each class that overrides shape should define it's own private properties for example circle should have a constant pi (because it never changes) and a property for the radius.  This will allow you to do other operations on the circle without having to redefine these variables.

Comment: Why have a constant in circle when it's already given by Math.Pi?